# Question about compact Hausdorff spaces with no isolation points being uncountable.

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres Topology I've just finished the proof of the statement:

Theorem: Let X be a non-empty compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points. Then
X is uncountable.

My question is that earlier in the text, when Hausdorff spaces were introduced, there was a theorem stating that all finite point sets in Hausdorff spaces were closed. So why do we need the added statement that there are no isolated points? Wouldn't $X$ being Hausdorff imply that there are no isolated points? Note that Munkres defines $x \in X$ to be isolated if $\{x\}$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Notice that the fact that an isolated point is open, does not imply that it isn't closed. I think that's what's confusing you.

Comment: @LorenzoQ.Yes I just remembered this. I need to stop thinking of sets like doors...

Comment: Spaces in which every subset is open or closed (or both) are actually called Door Spaces.

Comment: We can replace "compact" with "locally compact".  BTW: A non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set and is therefore an uncountable space. There is a proof that is very similar to a proof of your proposition. In both cases, the cardinal of the space is shown to be at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ regardless of the Continuum Hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, being Hausdorff does not mean that there are no isolated points. As an example, just take the integers with the usual metric, that is, the induced topology is the discrete topology. Since it is a metric space, it must be Hausdorff. Also, all points here are isolated points.